# How to center a string in elisp?

Tags: string, elisp, padding, center

I would like to center justify a given input string to a given size so that what is produced is a string with padded spaces either side (left and right) of the input string.

The code I have to do this:

```
(defun center-string (string size)
  (let* ((padding (/ (- size (length string)) 2))
         (lpad (+ (length string) padding))
         (lformat (format "%%%ds" lpad))
         (rformat (format "%%%ds" (- size))))
    (format rformat (format lformat string))))
```

And some test cases:

```
(center-string "KJF" 10)
 => "   KJF    "
(center-string "KF" 10)
 => "    KF    "
(center-string "0123456789" 10)
 => "0123456789"
(center-string "0123456789" 5)
 => "0123456789"       ; Notice justifcation is ignored as input string too large.
```

Is there an existing elisp function to do this or a better method?

Comment: Your question reminded me of the vi macro to center a string I saw long long time ago. A quick search came up with http://hydra.nac.uci.edu/indiv/gdh/vi/ which seems to be same as what I saw in mid nineties:

map =c 080i ^[$78hd0:s/ / /g^M

Please follow my link for explanation of the macro

Comment: Tag this one "downsides-of-porting-from-teco-to-lisp".  On second thought, never mind, we'll probably never need that tag again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not an existing emacs lisp routine that does what you want.  (the standard search through emacs lisp info and emacs info supports this).

Answer (score 1):

There's a `center-line`, which works in a buffer (and uses the buffer's value of `fill-column` as the line length), so if your goal is to produce a nicely formatted file, you could do something like

```
(defun insert-centered (x)
  (insert "\n" x)
  (center-line)
  (insert "\n"))
```